# Django HTML User authentication

Tags: python, html, django, authentication

I have a condition like this:

```
{% if object.author == user or object.res_person_1_username == user %}
```

If I view variables with, for example:

```
<p class="article-content mb-1"><strong>object.res_person_1_username: </strong>{{ object.res_person_1_username }}</p>
```

They are the same, all three, but condition

```
object.res_person_1_username == user
```

is always False. Why is that? What I'm missing? Do I need to change data type or something?

models.py

```
res_person_1_username = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=40)
```

Comment: You are comparing a username with a `User` object.

Comment: Are they both strings? or us one a user class and the other a text field?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: `user` is normally passed automatically to the template as `request.user` (that is why `request` is passed in the `render(...)` call, so this is a comparison between a `User` object and a string.

Comment: To make things simple, just change `res_person_1_username` in ur model.py to a Foreignkey and link it to auth User model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a username with a `User` object. A string `'foo'` is not the same as a `User` with `'foo'` as username.

You can check this with:

```
{% if object.author == user or object.res_person_1_username == user.username %}
```

But that being said, to refer to a model object, one normally uses a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). This guarantees referential integrity, makes filtering, querying, etc. more convenient, and will also create an index automatically for that column.

Comment: It worked flawlessly, thank you for your help